# Maintaining two separate icons

Tags: xml, wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

Does anyone have any idea on how to maintain two separate icons for the WiX bootstrapper executable and also the Add/Remove Programs icon?

For example, I have:

```
<Bundle ... IconSourceFile="blah.ico" ... />
```

But IconSourceFile sets **both** to the same icon. Its description reads:

> Path to an icon that will replace the default icon in the final Bundle
>   executable. This icon will also be displayed in Programs and Features
>   (also known as Add/Remove Programs).

**Edit**: I feel like this may be achieved through a custom action at the end of my installer that is part of the bundle to change the bootstrapper's Add/Remove Programs icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone already filed a feature request for this: http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4383/.  The WiX team suspended it, which means they have no intention of doing it but would accept a pull request if someone wants to implement it.